# Rails Querying for dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am seeing the current error in heroku (who is using pgsql)

```
2011-08-16T23:18:58+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end"
2011-08-16T23:18:58+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...".* FROM "deals" WHERE (start <= '2011-08-16' AND end > '201...
2011-08-16T23:18:58+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2011-08-16T23:18:58+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE (start <= '2011-08-16' AND end > '2011-08-16')):
2011-08-16T23:18:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/deals_helper.rb:7:in `currently_active'
2011-08-16T23:18:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `home'
```

This is generated by

```
d = Deal.where(["start <= ? AND end > ?", today, today])
```

I still want to continue developing on sqlite3. I do however want this to work on pgsql. Any ideas?

Comment: I finally figured it out. Turns out END is a keyword omg.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = Deal.where(["start <= '?' AND end > '?'", today, today])
```

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: near "2011": syntax error: SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE (start <= ''2011-08-16'' AND end > ''2011-08-16'')

Comment: Is today a string?  It needs to be Date.today or use strftime to parse the time.

Comment: Okay, don't know then.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think so:

```
d = Deal.where(["'start' <= ? AND 'end' > ?", today, today])
```

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: near "2011": syntax error: SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE ('start' <= ''2011-08-16'' AND 'end' > ''2011-08-16'')

Answer (score 0):

???

```
d = Deal.where(['start <= ? AND end > ?', today, today])
```

Comment: 2011-08-16T23:46:34+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end"
2011-08-16T23:46:34+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...".* FROM "deals" WHERE (start <= '2011-08-16' AND end > '201...
2011-08-16T23:46:34+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2011-08-16T23:46:34+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE (start <= '2011-08-16' AND end > '2011-08-16')):

Comment: d = Deal.where(['start <= "?" AND end > "?"', today, today])